# T-SQL Grouping Sets of Information

Tags: database, t-sql, group-by, analytics

I have a problem which my limited SQL knowledge is keeping me from understanding.

**First the problem:**

I have a database which I need to run a report on, it contains configurations of a users entitlements. The report needs to show a distinct list of these configurations and a count against each one.

So a line in my DB looks like this:

```
USER_ID SALE_ITEM_ID    SALE_ITEM_NAME  PRODUCT_NAME    CURRENT_LINK_NUM    PRICE_SHEET_ID
37715     547             CultFREE    CultPlus         0                561
```

the above line is one row of a users configuration, for every user ID there can be 1-5 of these lines. So the **definition of a configuration is** multiple rows of data sharing a common User ID with variable attributes..

I need to get a distinct list of these configurations across the whole table, leaving me just one configuration set for every instance where > 1 has that configuration and a count of instances of that configuration.

Hope this is clear?

Any ideas?!?!

I have tried various group by's and unions, also the grouping sets function to no avail.

Will be very greatful if anyone can give me some pointers!

Comment: so ... u need a distinct list of rows that apply to all users ? ... no that's not right

Comment: Im thinking I will need to create set ID's and then group on the set ID, so where a user has product x, y and z and other property xyz I will assign a set ID, another user found with that set of data will be given the same ID. I can then group on those ID's and I have the group that I want?

Comment: @Yoda please, put some more rows and what is the result that you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch that hurt ...

Ok so problem:

1. a row represents a configurable line
2. users may be linked to more than 1 row of configuration
3. configuration rows when grouped together form a configuration set
4. we want to figure out all of the distinct configuration sets
5. we want to know what users are using them.

Solution (its a bit messy but the idea is there, copy and paste in to SQL management studio) ...

```
-- ok so i imported the data to a table named SampleData ... 
-- 1. import the data 
-- 2. add a new column
-- 3. select all the values of the config in to the new column (Configuration_id)
--UPDATE [dbo].[SampleData]
--SET [Configuration_ID] = SALE_ITEM_ID + SALE_ITEM_NAME + [PRODUCT_NAME] + [CURRENT_LINK_NUM] + [PRICE_SHEET_ID] + [Configuration_ID]

-- 4. i then selected just the distinct values of those and found 6 distinct Configuration_id's 
--SELECT DISTINCT [Configuration_ID] FROM [dbo].[SampleData]

-- 5. to make them a bit easier to read and work with i gave them int values instead 
--    for me it was easy to do this manually but you might wanna do some trickery here to autonumber them or something 
--    basic idea is to run the step 4 statement but select into a new table then add a new primary key column and set identity spec on it
--    that will generate u a bunch of incremental numbers for your config id's so u can then do something like ...
--UPDATE [dbo].[SampleData] sd
--SET Configuration_ID = (SELECT ID FROM TempConfigTable WHERE Config_ID = sd.Configuration_ID)

-- at this point you have all your existing rows with a unique ident for the values combined in each row.
-- so for example in my dataset i have several rows where only the user_id has changed but all look like this ...
--SALE_ITEM_ID  SALE_ITEM_NAME  PRODUCT_NAME    CURRENT_LINK_NUM    PRICE_SHEET_ID  Configuration_ID
--54101 TravelFREE  TravelPlus  0   56101   1

-- now you have a config id you can start to work on building sets up ...
-- each user is now matched with 1 or more config id 
-- 6. we use a CTE (common table expression) to link the possibles (keeps the join small) ...
--WITH Temp (ConfigID)
--AS
--(
--  SELECT DISTINCT SD.Configuration_Id --SD2.Configuration_Id, SD3.Configuration_Id, SD4.Configuration_Id, SD5.Configuration_Id, 
--  FROM [dbo].[SampleData] SD
--)
-- this extracts all the possible combinations using the CTE
-- on the basis of what you told me, max rows per user is 6, in the result set i have i only have 5 distinct configs
-- meaning i gain nothing by doing a 6th join.
-- cross joins basically give you every combination of unique values from the 2 tables but we joined back on the same table 
-- so its every possible combination of Temp + Temp (ConfigID + ConfigID) ... per cross join so with 5 joins its every combination of 
-- Temp + Temp + Temp + Temp + Temp .. good job temp only has 1 column with 5 values in it
-- 7. uncomment both this and the CTE above ... need to use them together
--SELECT DISTINCT T.ConfigID C1, T2.ConfigID C2, T3.ConfigID C3, T4.ConfigID C4, T5.ConfigID C5
--INTO [SETS]
--FROM Temp T
--CROSS JOIN Temp T2
--CROSS JOIN Temp T3
--CROSS JOIN Temp T4
--CROSS JOIN Temp T5

-- notice the INTO clause ... this dumps me out a new [SETS] table in my db
-- if i go add a primary key to this and set its ident spec i now have unique set id's 
-- for each row in the table.
--SELECT *
--FROM [dbo].[SETS]

-- now here's where it gets interesting ... row 1 defines a set as being config id 1 and nothing else 
-- row 2 defines set 2 as being config 1 and config 2 and nothing else ... and so on ...
-- the problem here of course is that 1,2,1,1,1 is technically the same set as 1,1,1,2,1 from our point of view
-- ok lets assign a set to each userid ...
-- 8. first we pull the distinct id's out ...
--SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID usr, null SetID 
--INTO UserSets
--FROM SampleData 

-- now we need to do bit a of operating on these that's a bit much for a single update or select so ...
-- 9. process findings in a loop
DECLARE @currentUser int
DECLARE @set int
-- while theres a userid not linked to a set
WHILE EXISTS(@currentUser = SELECT TOP 1 usr FROM UserSets WHERE SetId IS NULL)
BEGIN
    -- figure out a set to link it to
    SET @set = (
        SELECT TOP 1 ID 
        FROM [SETS]
        -- shouldn't really do this ... basically need to refactor in to a table variable then compare to that
        -- that way the table lookup on ur main data is only 1 per User_id
        WHERE C1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Configuration_id FROM SampleData WHERE USER_ID = @currentUser)
        AND C2 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Configuration_id FROM SampleData WHERE USER_ID = @currentUser)
        AND C3 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Configuration_id FROM SampleData WHERE USER_ID = @currentUser)
        AND C4 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Configuration_id FROM SampleData WHERE USER_ID = @currentUser)
        AND C5 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Configuration_id FROM SampleData WHERE USER_ID = @currentUser)
    )
    -- hopefully that worked 
    IF(@set IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN 
        -- tell the usersets table 
        UPDATE UserSets SET SetId = @set WHERE usr = @currentUser
        set @set = null
    END
    ELSE -- something went wrong ... set to 0 to prevent endless loop but any userid linked to set 0 is a problem u need to look at
        UPDATE UserSets SET SetId = 0 WHERE usr = @currentUser
    -- and round we go again ... until we are done
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
USER_ID,
SALE_ITEM_ID, ETC...,
COUNT(*) WhateverYouWantToNameCount

FROM TableNAme
GROUP BY USER_ID
```

Comment: I hope I didn't miss some subtlety in your question since you say you already tried a group by.

Comment: This will give me a count of attributes within a users configuration, I need to group by the configurations of every user, leaving me a set of configurations and the number of instances of each. thanks anyway

Comment: Ok then please update your question to be more specific about what you want to group, I can't understand what you want from what you have posted. Are you asking how many times unique combinations of the columns other than user_id appear?